# iso - Loading a local php file UIWebView and adding information

Tags: php, ios, nsstring, code-injection

I have a properly coded HTML page that I can display in my app.

The file is embedded locally inside the app, but it pulls in data from an API.
It is a Rest API that works with PHP.

So my question now is - is it possible to have NSString inject it's value into the php file so that it can display the required result, or are PHP and Objective-c not designed to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to actually parse and execute PHP in your iOS app, I am afraid you are probably out of luck.

If you simply want to dynamically update certain elements on a static HTML page and leverage a PHP service to do it, your best bet is probably to use javascript and AJAX to put the dynamic content from the service.

Alternatively, you can treat the HTML file like a template, make a call to the PHP service to get the dynamic content; merge that content into the template and display the template.

I guess what is most appropriate in your case, will ultimately depend on your desired user experience.

Comment: I have this particular line : $passage = urlencode("john 3:16");  which I would like to update to $passage = urlencode("NSString Value"); I hope that makes my picture a bit clearer. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What I am saying is that you can't run your PHP in iOS. I got the impression that iOS needed to populate a value from a PHP service, but it sounds like you are needing o get teh template from PHP and then populate with a value known in Objective C.  In which case, you just need to throw PHP out the window, and have your objectiveC code populate values into an HTML template.

Comment: Yes I have the solution now - I found out that the API output plain text so there is no issue now:-)